# How to get product id in the link of ProductPage in React?

Tags: reactjs

It's one of the products in products.js array

```
const products = [
    {
        id:1,
        name:"ORGANIC CABBAGES/TIPS & GUIDES",
        title:"Tips for Ripening your Fruit",
        description:"Cabbage (comprising several cultivars of Brassica oleracea) is a leafy green, red (purple), or white (pale green) biennial plant",
        date:17,
        month:"Nov",
        image:"/ProductsImages/post1.jpg",
    },

export const getProductsObject = array => array.reduce((obj,product) => ({
    ...obj,
    [product.id]:product
}),{})


export default products
```

That's Route in Main.js

```
<Route path="/products/:id" component={ProductPage}/>
```

That is ProductPages component:

```
import React from 'react'
import products, { getProductsObject } from '../Products/products'

const ProductPage = ({
    match,
    productsObject = getProductsObject(products)
}) => {
    const id = match.params.id
    console.log(match)
    return (
        <>
            <h1 className="page-title">Product Page</h1>
        </>
    )
}

export default ProductPage
```

id is undefined in localhost3000. I don't know how to solve this problem.

Comment: where is __id__ variable defined?

Comment: Can you post the whole code in your question, not in a comment?

Comment: If it's a code block, put it inside ` characters

Comment: Put the whole __ProductListItem__ component code here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to access the id property at ProductPage - you should use - useParams() hook, like this -

`const { id } = useParams()`

and you'll get the id you passed to the params (id will be the value you sent).

Comment: Thank you, bro. I'll definitely try it.